# Need help to create a form to get records on basis of search of last name and years

Tags: javascript, json

i created a table in json . I need to create a search button for the user to enter a search form that searches the employee records on the basis of Last Name and  The program must also list those employees who are born between two years input by user.

```js
{
"employee1":{"Emp_Id" :"ID-101" ,"F_Name" : "Chrish" ,"L_Name" : "Harish" ,"Year" : "1980" ,"Department" : "Computer"},
"employee2":{"Emp_Id" :"ID-102" ,"F_Name" : "Robin" ,"L_Name" : "Smith" ,"Year" : "1984" ,"Department" : "Business"},
"employee3":{"Emp_Id" :"ID-103" ,"F_Name" : "Jessica" ,"L_Name" : "Hudson" ,"Year" : "1974" ,"Department" : "Human Resource"}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>In Class 2</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="inclass()">inclass</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function inclass()
{
var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("GET","ICemp.json",true);
xml.send();                                        //for sending request
xml.onreadystatechange=function()                 //checks if the data is sent

 {
 var data=JSON.parse(xml.responseText);  

 document.write("<table border='1'>")
   document.write("<tr>");
   document.write("<td rowspan ='1'>" +"Emp_Id" +"</td>" +"<td colspan ='1'>" + "F_Name" +"</td>" +"<td colspan ='1'>" +"L_Name" +"</td>"+ "<td colspan ='1'>" + "Year" +"</td>" +"<td rowspan ='1'>" + "Department" +"</td>");
   document.write("</tr>");
  
for(var ob in data)
         { 
   document.write("<tr>");
           document.write("<td>"+ data[ob].Emp_Id + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>"+ data[ob].F_Name + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>"+ data[ob].L_Name + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>"+ data[ob].Year + "</td>");
     document.write("<td>"+ data[ob].Department + "</td>");
     document.write("</tr>");
          }
    document.write("</table>");
 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide code samples.

Comment: Please edit your code into your original post.

Comment: I am sorry for m not really familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the code

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function(){

  var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("GET","ICemp.json",true);
xml.send();                                        //for sending request
xml.onreadystatechange=function()                 //checks if the data is sent

 {
 var data=JSON.parse(xml.responseText); 
 $('#here_table').empty();


      var $table = $('<table/>');
       $table.append("<td rowspan ='1'>" +"Emp_Id" +"</td>" +"<td colspan ='1'>" + "F_Name" +"</td>" +"<td colspan ='1'>" +"L_Name" +"</td>"+ "<td colspan ='1'>" + "Year" +"</td>" +"<td rowspan ='1'>" + "Department" +"</td>");
for(var ob in data){
    $table.append( '<tr><td>' +  data[ob].Emp_Id + '</td><td>' +  data[ob].F_Name + '</td><td>' +  data[ob].L_Name + '</td><td>' +  data[ob].Year + '</td><td>' +  data[ob].Department + '</td></tr>' );
}
$('#here_table').append($table);




 }
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if ('' != this.value) {
        var reg = new RegExp(this.value, 'i'); // case-insesitive

        $('table').find('tr').each(function() {
            var $me = $(this);
            if (!$me.children('td').text().match(reg)) {
                $me.hide();
            } else {
                $me.show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('table').find('tr').show();
    }
});


});
```

and HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input placeholder="search name" id="search">
    <div id="here_table"> </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

for your reference https://plnkr.co/edit/Y53vavWFe8EW3TTCpOL2?p=preview

so the search option will search based on the key u enter